# Is the mutability of Swift containers shallow? Or can an element be mutated in place?

Tags: swift, containers, mutable

I have a collection of objects in a `Set`. The objects' type follows `GeneratorType`, so I have a mutating method `next`. Although I can mutate the set by adding/removing elements, I don't know how to mutate an element.  Using both `for-in` statement and the `forEach` method give errors about the element being immutable. Is the mutability of Swift containers shallow?

Is there a way to call a mutating method on a contained element?  Does it work for other collection/sequence types besides `Set`?  (My changes would change each object's hash, and maybe I'm not allowed to affect a set like that.)

Comment: What specific type is the Set carrying (Int, String, etc. if custom, specify if struct or class)? Is the Set declared with `let`?

Comment: @TroyT, I'm using a custom `struct` with `var` properties in a `var` top-level object (of a playground).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation is similar to that of mutating one of a dictionary's values, where that value is a value type. You can't do it, even if your reference to the dictionary is a `var` reference. Typically, you'll just pull the value out, mutate it, and put it back again:

```
var d = ["key":"hell"]
var val = d["key"]!
val.append(Character("o"))
d["key"] = val
```

Your Set works similarly.

```
var s = Set(["hell"])
var val = s.remove("hell")!
val.append(Character("o"))
s.insert(val)
```

There are other ways to notate that, but in effect they amount to the same thing.

The thing to keep in mind here is that no value type, e.g. a struct, is *truly* mutable. We speak of it as if it were, and so does Swift with its `mutating` functions, but mutation actually consists of assigning a new value back into the reference. That is *why* the reference must be a `var`. There is thus *no such thing* as mutation in place for *any* value type.

Now, of course, with a reference type, e.g. a class, the situation is completely different:

```
let s = Set([NSMutableString(string:"hell")])
s.first!.appendString("o")
s // {"hello"}
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I'm done editing my answer now. :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. I slept on it and tried out other containers besides `Set`, on my initial speculation that Swift wouldn't let me invalidate container indices. (A `Set` uses it own elements as indices.) I could change the values (but not keys) of a `Dictionary`. For an `Array`, I had to use `enumerate`, use only the indices, and manipulate the elements that way; direct manipulation through `forEach` is still set to `let` mode. Although using `(var element) in` for `forEach` is accepted by the compiler, the actual mutations are ignored (proved through later inspection)!

Comment: It seems that the fine control over (im)mutability and/or value-vs.-reference C++ gives on a per-method basis does have its advantages. If you don't like Swift's defaults on these matters, it'll fight you most of the time.