# How to implement read-only var with mutating get

Tags: swift

I have a var

```
var soketTasksList:Set<SocketTask> {
   get { return socketManager.tasksList }
}
```

I don't need to set, only get,
but I need do something like this

```
soketTasksList.remove(task)
```

but compiler says

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value is a get-only property

I tried to add the keyword 'mutating' to the get, but this isn't working. I also
tried to add 'mutating' to the var, but this isn't working either.

**UPD**
i dont undestand why do I need set?
if i do

```
func getSoketTasksList() -> Set<CXSocketTask> {
    return socketManager.tasksList
}
```

i can

```
getSoketTasksList().remove(task)
```

why not with var?

Comment: but then it will not be read-only, i don't need do set, i need mutating result from my var

Comment: Is your tasksList declared to be mutable?

Comment: A read-only computed property cannot be mutated without a setter method. Even though you don't need to mutate the the variable holding the list, it will inadvertently make the list immutable.

Comment: "i can `getSoketTasksList().remove(task)`" No, you can't! You keep digging yourself deeper into a world of delusion. Try to listen: Set is not NSMutableSet. Set is a Swift value type. NSMutableSet is an Objective-C reference type. If you want to pass a mutable reference around, use NSMutableSet. If you're going to use Swift types, learn how Swift types work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i don't need to set, only get

Yes, you *do* need to set.

> i need do something like this `soketTasksList.remove(task)`

That is a mutation. Mutating a [value type like Set](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27366050/341994) requires the ability to set. But you have cut off that possibility by making this a read-only computed variable.

---

> UPD i dont undestand why do I need set? if i do
>
> ```
>    func getSoketTasksList() -> Set<CXSocketTask> {
>        return socketManager.tasksList
>    }
> ```
>
> i can
>
> ```
>    getSoketTasksList().remove(task)
> ```

No you can't. Try it. Here's a playground test:

```
class CXSocketTask:NSObject{}
class SocketManager {
    var tasksList = Set<CXSocketTask>()
}
let task = CXSocketTask()
let socketManager = SocketManager()
socketManager.tasksList.insert(task)

func getSoketTasksList() -> Set<CXSocketTask> {
    return socketManager.tasksList
}
getSoketTasksList().remove(task)
```

The last line generates an error: "cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'getSoketTasksList' returns immutable value".

Comment: See for example my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36000944/341994 As I explain there, a value type is not mutable _in place_. A move like `remove` requires that we be able to _write back to the reference_. But that is exactly what a read-only variable cannot do.

Comment: but i get from var link to object, this is not copy object. and if its link i can do with object anything

Comment: @EvGeniyIlyin You can _say_ that, but you're wrong. Programming is about facing _reality_, not going with what you _believe_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use temporary variable for this purpose:

```
var list = soketTasksList
list.remove(task)
```

Note that underlying list (`socketManager.tasksList` in this case) remains untouched.

Comment: "Note that underlying list remains untouched" You're absolutely right, but then it _doesn't_ meet the purpose. He _wants_ to mutate the underlying list. And he simply can't do that if his reference to that list is by way of a read-only computed variable.

Answer (score 0):

The only situation in which you can do this is if the actual mutating is done through something which is settable.

For example:

```
struct Person {
  var age: Int = 1

  mutating func setAge(a: Int) -> Int {
    age = a
    return a
  }

  var computedAge: Int {
    mutating get {
      setAge(a: 4)
      return age
    }
  }
}

var person = Person()
print(person.computedAge) //Prints 4
```

This is by design